# $R$ is an algebra over an infinite field. If $\exists$ ideals s.t. $J\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^nI_k$ then $J\subseteq I_k$ for some $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

> Let $R$ be a ring and let $I_1,\dots,I_n,J\subseteq R$ be ideals such that $J\subseteq I_1\cup\dots\cup I_n$. Suppose that there exists an infinite field $K$ and a homomorphism $\phi:K\to R$. Prove that $\exists k$ s.t. $J\subseteq I_k$.

**Attempt:** (Edited)

If $J\subseteq I_1$ then we're done. Otherwise, let $x\in I_1$ and let $y\in J\setminus I_1$. $\forall r\in K, x+ry\notin I_1$ (because otherwise we'll get $y\in I_1$).

$K$ is infinite so we have infinitely many elements of the form $x+ry\in J$. So there's some $k$ for which $I_k$ contains infintely many elements of the former form.

If $n=2$ so $x+y\notin I_1$ implies $$x+y\in I_2\Rightarrow x\in I_1\Rightarrow I_1\subset I_2\Rightarrow J\subseteq I_2$$

Suppose the theorem holds for some $n$. $x+y\notin I_1\Rightarrow \exists k,I_k\ni x+ry$ for infintely many elements as above.

Comment: Assume that $J$ is a $k$-vector space contained in a big vector space $R$, and $I_k, k=1,...n$  is a familiy of sub vector spaces of $R$, such that $J\subset I_1\cup ...\cup I_n$, can you prove that $J$ is contained in one of the $I_j$ (a picture may help there). This implies your result.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26

Comment: I've edited my attempt regarding your comments, I'll aprriciate if you can guide me again.

Comment: You can proceed by induction, first treat the case $n=2$.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it.

Comment: If you take $V$ a sub vector space of a vector space $E$, such that $V\subset W\cup W'$ then if you have neither $V\subset W$ nor $V\subset W'$ you can find $a,b\in V$ s.t $a\in W$, $a\notin W'$ and $b\in W'$ and $b\notin W$, then $a+b$ is in $V$ so it is in $W$ or $W'$, say $W$, but that would imply that $b=a+b-a$ lies in $W$.

Comment: As you may have noticed I haven't used the fact that $k$ is infinite, do you see how to modify the argument (and use the non finiteness of $k$) so that it will work for $n$ spaces instead of $2$?

Comment: Actually I don't see. @Ahr

Comment: I've given a complete proof below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution, it has nothing to do with commutative algebra, this is purely linear algebra.
Let's proceed by induction.
The case $n=1$, is obvious. I've treated the case $n=2$, in the comment above.

Assume that we have proved the result for $1,..., N-1$, and take $E$ a $k$-vector space, $W_1,...,W_N$ sub vector spaces of $E$ and $V$ a sub vector space contained in $W_1\cup...\cup W_N$.

If $V\subset W_1$ we're done, and if $V\subset W_2\cup...\cup W_N$ we're done too by the induction hypothesis.

So we may assume that we can find $x\in V$ s.t $x\in W_1$, $x\notin W_2\cup...\cup W_N$ and $y\in W_2\cup...\cup W_N$ and $y\notin W_1$.

As $k$ is infinite, the elements $x+ty$ are all in $V$ and there a infintely many of them, so 2 of them must lie in a $W_k$.

Wa have 2 case, if $x+ty$ and $x+sy$ both lie in $W_1$, with $s\neq t$, then $y$ lies in $W_1$ which we excluded. If $x+ty$ and $x+sy$ both lie in $W_k$ for some $k>1$ and $s\neq t$, then certainly $s\neq 0$ and $t\neq 0$ otherwise $x$ would lie in $W_k$, thus $x/s+y$ and $x/t+y$ lie in $W_k$ thus $x.(1/s-1/t)$ lies in $W_k$, which again is excluded.

As ideals are in particular $k$-sub vector spaces of the $k$-algebra $R$, this implies your statement.